# How initialize dropdown (<select/>) with preselected value and then change it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, select

I've got a grid with dropdown in every row and I need to render it's state from DB.
So I've got dropdowns defined like that with selected option specified for preselecting the value from DB.

```
<select id='selectId'>
<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='2' selected='selected'>Option 2</option>
<option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>​
```

The problem is in that when I change the value of a dropdown defined like that in a browser it changes on UI but selected attribute don't move and stays where it was.
So when I then call $("#selectId").val() I get the old one value.

What's the appropriate way to initialize dropdown control and then have an ability to freely change it's value in browser or by jQuery?

Comment: To clarify, your problem is that when you use the code above, marking `option value='2'` as `selected` will set Option 2 to be selected by default and you cannot chose any other option.

Comment: When you say "by hand", you mean through jQuery code or not?

Comment: @Jonathan Eckman, I understand that now. And can you give an advice how to preselect dropdown value from html, not js? Maybe I have to use above code and after grid rendered remove all "selected" value from all dropdowns?


icyrock.com, I mean in browser. NOT with js (jQ).

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with at least the form and div holding it? I have had the problem I think you are describing in the past but am unable to recreate it to figure out how it was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working fine (Firefox on Ubuntu):

HTML

```
<select id='selectId'>
<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='2' selected='selected'>Option 2</option>
<option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('#selectId').change(function() {
    var opt = $(this).find('option:selected');
    console.log([opt.val(), opt.text()]);   
});

var opt_sel = $('#selectId option:selected');
opt_sel.val(99);
opt_sel.text('Changed option');
```

If you select the options, you'll see that it will print the changed version. Working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vm4Q8/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It should work fine. May be you are not setting it correctly.

You should pass the `value` of the option to `val()` method to select it.

E.g `$('#selectId').val('1');` will set first option as selected and afterwards calling `$('#selectId').val()` will give you `1` and not `2`.

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/3eu85/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the val of the option selected, instead of the select

```
$('select#selectId option:selected').val();
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you trying this in? Your code looks fine to me, and appears to be working in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGnUj/).

Answer (score 0):

please use this code instead,

```
$('#selectId option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to set it value '2' on loading the webpage.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#selectId').val('2');
    });
</script>
```